# How to print a list of arrays transposed in a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, transpose

I have a list that contains arrays (type = numpy.ndarray) in the following form:

```
final = [[a, b, c, d],[e, f, g, h],[i, j, k, l]]
```

and i would like to print them transposed in a csv file in the following form:

```
a, e, i
b, f, j
c, g, k
d, h, l
```

where a,b,c...j, k, l are all strings (numpy.string_).
I tried to approach this as a list containing lists (which is answered in another post) but it does not work, instead in creates an empty csv file.
My attempt was this one:

```
csvfile=open('new.csv','wb')    
wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
final=map(list, zip(*final))
wr.writerows(final)
csvfile.close()
```

Can somebody offer some advice?

Comment: `it does not work:` - Please explain the actual problem

Comment: a,b,c,d all are strings right?

Comment: Yes they all are numpy.string_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your list to a numpy array: `final = np.array(final)` and then use the transpose method `numpy.ndarray.T` this way:

`final.T = [[a, e, i],[b, f, j],[c, g, k],[d,h,l]]`

So:

```py
import numpy as np
np.savetxt("foo.csv", np.array(final).T, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('new.csv', 'wb') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerows(map(list, zip(*final)))
```